# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread' on python anywhere

Tags: rest, flask

**What I am trying to achieve.**

Run a python script saved On pythonanywhere host from google sheets on a button press.

[Check the answer by Dustin Michels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66655415/running-a-python-script-saved-in-local-machine-from-google-sheets-on-a-button-pr/66832109#66832109)

**Task of Each File?**

**app.py**: contains code of REST API made using Flask.

**runMe.py**: contains code for that get values from(google sheet cell A1:A2). And sum both values send sum back to A3.

**main.py**:  contains code for a GET request with an argument as name(runMe.py).filename may change if the user wants to run another file.

I Made an API by using Flask.it works online and offline perfectly but still, if you want to recommend anything related to the app.py.[Code Review App.py](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259266/run-python-file-with-get-request-flask-api/259290#259290)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class callApi(Resource):
    def get(self, file_name):
        my_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, file_name)
        file = open(file_path)
        getvalues = {}
        exec(file.read(), getvalues)
        return jsonify({'data': getvalues['total']})


api.add_resource(callApi, "/callApi/<string:file_name>")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here is the Code of runMe2.py

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API

scopes =['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('service_account.json', scopes)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("Demosheet").sheet1


# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

below is the main.py code

```
import requests

BASE = 'https://username.pythonanywhere.com/callApi/test.py'

response = requests.get(BASE)
print(response.json())
```

main.py output

```
{'data': 54}
```

Test.py code

```
a = 20
b = 34
total = a+b
print(total)
```

**PROBLEM IS**

if I request runMe2.py at that time I am got this error.
check runMe2.py code above

app.py is hosted on https://www.pythonanywhere.com/

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'
```

However, I installed gspread on pythonanywhere why using the command. but it's not working.

Comment: How have you installed module `gspread`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either haven't installed the `gspread` package on your current python environment or it is installed somewhere (e.g. in a diff. virtual env) and your script cant find it.

Try installing the package inside the environment your running your script in using pip3:

```
pip3 install gspread
```

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- this is the correct answer, I think.  Another possibility as to why the OP couldn't import it after installing it (apart from a virtualenv) is that they might have installed it for a different Python version -- that is, for Python 3.7 when their site is using Python 3.8 -- so I'd suggest using a full version number in the `pip` command, like `pip3.8` rather than just `pip3`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this on Windows

```
pip install gspread
```

or on Mac

```
pip3 install gspread
```

If you're running on Docker, or building with a requirements.txt you can try adding this line you your requirements.txt file

```
gspread==3.7.0
```

Any other instructions for this package can be found here => https://github.com/burnash/gspread

Answer (score 0):

[Download gspread here](https://pypi.org/project/gspread/#files)

Download the tar file: gspread-3.7.0.tar.gz from the above link
Extract file and convert folder in zip then upload it back on server

Open bash console and use command as

```
$ unzip gspread-3.7.0
$ cd gspread-3.7.0
$ python3.7 setup.py install --user
```